# Java Application not working after Packaging into jar file

Tags: java, json, gradle, libgdx

I had a java app working properly by Intellij IDEA but not working after packaging into jar file

what are the possible causes ?
and how can I find the mistake ?

the app is a `gradle` project (`libgdx`) and I packaged it by command line `gradlew desktop:dist`

it give me this

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRun timeException: Error reading file: json\levels.json <Absolute>
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read<FileHandle.java:144>
```

Comment: run it from cmd to see errors

Comment: do you have any stacktrace or could you elaborate what 'not working' means?

Comment: "what are the possible causes" too many to fit in one answer :)

Comment: please add your Error stacktrace to identify the error cause.

Comment: The two packages methods are obviously different and are creating different artefacts. As has already been suggested, reproduce your stack trace. If possible compare what has been built by gradle and IntelliJ. There has to be some differences in there.

Comment: Have you already tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25138314/com-badlogic-gdx-utils-gdxruntimeexception-couldnt-load-file-error

Comment: that mostly indicates a missing file (exactly "level.json"), if you have path like this in your code "levels/level.json" then in the folder that contains the result jar file there should be folder "levels" with your "level.json" inside it

Comment: we can say the same for any relative path in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After packaging the application JAR file, is the JSON file part of the JAR? Then you have to change the way of accessing the file. You can't access a file through an absolute file path, but instead you should use

```java
InputStream in = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("path/to/file/in/jar")
```